# Is there a clean wikipedia API just for retrieve image by article name?

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I need just to retrieve image inside a Wikipedia page with a specific size, and image may have description plus width and height.

**Update:**

I am asking about retrieve All images inside wikipedia article Not wikipedia article main images!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing main picture of wikipedia page by API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363531/accessing-main-picture-of-wikipedia-page-by-api)

Comment: Yes there is. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363531/accessing-main-picture-of-wikipedia-page-by-api and multiple other questions

Comment: I am asking about retrieve All images inside wikipedia article Not wikipedia article main images!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve all images from a MediaWiki article, query for [the `images` property](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Images):

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=images&titles=Main%20Page
```

Then you can [ask for paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312055/programatically-determining-the-url-of-a-mediawiki-image) to [specific sizes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Imageinfo):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Bubolz%20Grass.jpg&prop=imageinfo&&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=220
```

Finally, you can use the first query as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) for the second, to get all the data in one request:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=images&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=imageinfo&&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=220
```

Note that this is part of the MediaWiki core API, and not specific to Wikipedia or even the Wikimedia universe.

Comment: Can i get images with info in one connection!

Comment: Yes, please read the documentation on generators I linked to. You can use the first guery as a generator for the second!

Comment: Thank you for your help.
[Albert Einstein Images](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=images&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=imageinfo&&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=220)